# How to append innerHTML of a button on Ember.view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have created a view for button.

```
App.NumberButtonView = Ember.View.extend({
tagName: 'button',
classNames: ['ButtonClass']
});
```

My button model is

```
App.NumberBtns = DS.Model.extend({
value: DS.attr('string'),
width: DS.attr('string'),
height: DS.attr('string'),
className: DS.attr('string'),
type:DS.attr('string')
```

})

```
App.NumberBtns.FIXTURES = [  {
id: '108',
value: '8',
style: {
    width: '50px',
    height: '50px'
},
className: 'NumberBtnClass',
type: 'number',
}, {
id: '109',
value: '9',
style: {
    width: '50px',
    height: '50px'
},
className: 'NumberBtnClass',
type: 'number',
}, {
id: '110',
value: '0',
style: {
    width: '50px',
    height: '50px'
},
className: 'NumberBtnClass',
type: 'number',
```

}
]

How can i pass the value of the button to the view from the controller.

We can do it by adding tags  and appending the innerHTML. But how to append the innerHTML in the buttonView from model through controller

Answer (score 0):

We can set the controller using

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
```

to display the name use itemBinding

```
{{#each btn in model.operatorBtn}}
{{#view App.NumberButtonView itemBinding="btn"}}
<i> {{view.item.value}} </i>
{{/view}}
 {{/view}}
 {{/each}
```

Now the value will get displayed in the view.